# How to use a regex to get a primary key from a URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm new in rewriting URLs. So far I've rewritten a couple of them successfully but I can't "catch" the `$_GET` variables, I've tried everything. Here is my script:

```
$item_name = (isset($_GET["item_name"])) ? $_GET["item_name"] : "";
$item_id = (isset($_GET["item_id"])) ? $_GET["item_id"] : "";

echo $item_name;
echo $item_id;
```

Here is the htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^categories localhost/folder/folder/categories.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home  localhost/folder/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^pictures  localhost/folder/folder/stuff.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^account localhost/folder/folder/account.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^articles localhost/folder/folder/articles.php [NC,L]
```

What I'm really trying to do is catch the `$_GET["item_name"]` and the `$_GET["item_id"]` out of the new clean URL `localhost/folder/home/guitar/123`.

This is what I've got to try to accomplish the above, and doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^home/(0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ htaccess/index.php?item_name=$1&item_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

This gives me some of the variables but is not quite what I want:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?item_name=$1&item_id [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (and you'll need this *before* your other rules):

```
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ localhost/folder/index.php?item_name=$1&item_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```